# Field initialization cannot reference non-static field? How to work around it?

Tags: c#, static, initialization, field

I'm referring to some code from the book [C# concurrency in action], the chapter has following code snippet:

```
int _v1;
readonly Lazy<int> Myv1 = new Lazy<int>(() => _v1++);//error
void UseV1()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Myv1.Value);
}

int _v2;
readonly Lazy<Task<int>> Myv2 = new Lazy<Task<int>>(async () =>//error
{
    await Task.Delay(2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return _v2++;
});
```

It doesn't compile, saying that

```
error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Program._v1'
```

Why this rule happens, how to fix or get around this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: What @John said * 2

Comment: Also you might want to have a look at this https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html

Comment: Is the code in the book error-prone?

Comment: If that's exactly as it's printed, then I'd say yes, unless the book goes on to explain why this doesn't work.